# How many anagrams are there for the word "MERCABLE" with given conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

I couldn't figure out an answer. Got several different answers, actually. Could someone try it? Here it goes.

> How many anagrams are there for the word "MERCABLE" with "M" as  the first letter, or "E" as the second letter or "R" as the third letter? Consider that the first letter is the one far to the left; for example, in "ABCD", the first letter would be "A", second would be "B", etc. Also, consider that the logical connective "or" is non-exclusive.

Comment: what is an "anagram" here? Just a permutation of the letters?

Comment: @Masacroso  That is what anagram means.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Yes! I tried using it, but I didn't find the correct answer. I called $M$ the set of all anagrams that has $M$ as the first letter, and did the same for $E$ and $R$. Then I used $n(M\cup E\cup R) = n(M) + n(E) + n(R) - n(M\cap R) - n(M\cap E) - n(E\cap R) + n(M\cap E\cap R)$. The problem is, didn't get the answer.

Comment: Your strategy is correct, but it would be easier to detect any errors if you actually showed your calculations.  The tricky thing about this problem is that there are two E's, which means the terms will not be symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By PIE (principal of inclusion and exclusion), we first count the number of ways such that $n(M) + n(E) + n(R)$. This is equivalent to $\frac{7!}{2} + 7! + \frac{7!}{2} = 2 \cdot 7! = 10080$ (since in the first and third cases, we have two $E$'s, so we divide by $2$.

Now, we subtract $n(M \cap E) + n(M \cap R) + n(E \cap R)$, which is $6! + \frac{6!}{2}  + 6! = 1800$. Finally we add back $n(M \cap E \cap R) = 5! = 120$, so the answer should be $10080 - 1800 + 120 = \boxed{9120}$